# Android problems when import library project using IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am not sure why I cannot import the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity class. I looked at and followed the steps described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317101/android-problems-when-import-library-project-using-eclipse) to change the jar file of the project. However in the solution the first step was to delete the jar file that was already there, I however did not have that file. I am not using gradle.

This is code I got from the android tutorial.

```
    package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActvity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        }
}
```

The error that comes up first is

```
Error:(5, 30) java: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
```

In the manifest also wrote this line.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

I assume this is okay because I would need to make sure that v7 stuff is supported. As mentioned in the title I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle?

Comment: No I do not, I don't know how to use either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA and not Android Studio (gradle based), you 
should add the library by going to File > Project Structure

then go to your module, tab Dependencies, and add the jar file from there.

Jar files in `libs` are not automatically added in IntelliJ, you have to manually add them as dependencies.

Comment: I was able to do that for both jar files, even thought I probably only need one. However it is still not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in build.gradle in dependencies

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'`

Comment: I am not using gradle.

Comment: change the compilesdkversion to `21` and add this libary to your project properties.. follow this tutorial and see `https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html`